# How works statics variables in .Net and C++?

Tags: .net, c++, variables

Static variables. in NET work differently to global variables that compile to native languages​​like C++ or Fortran? Why?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the precise differences that you are referring to?

Comment: I want to know the basics differences betwen static variables in .Net and globals variables in languages like C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no semantic difference. A static field is just a fancy name for a global variable.

Comment: +1 Because I share similar sentiments ;-) However, some people prefer to argue that static variables "are not global variables" because they are tied to a particular class/namespace.

Comment: @pst: In C++ you can scope global variables in namespaces, which achieves pretty much the same thing.

Comment: A *public* static field is just a global variable with a fancy name.

Comment: @Ben Voight The difference between a `static` ("private") global variable and an extern'able ("public") global variable in C is then..? (I would argue the difference is not in the visibility, but rather in the attachment -- or non-attachment -- to a particular "object" as well as the usage pattern(s) of such).

Comment: @pst: `static` file scoped variables aren't global.  If you refer to them in multiple compilation units, you get multiple copies.

Comment: @Ben Voight Exactly -- but they are still "shared across N functions" [with no enforcement of usage except convention] -- e.g. global? (None of the other files have to pull in/use the extern's)

Comment: @pst: Instance members are "shared across multiple functions", but we certainly wouldn't call them global.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Right, but they are "attached" to some particular object.

Comment: @pst: I'm agreeing with you that private static members and static file-scoped variables are analogous.  But neither one is really "global".  Both provide compiler enforcement of limited visibility/accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are usually accessible without any limitation. This is also the reason they are often considered evil as you cannot take any care of keeping other parts of your code from misusing then, and errors concerning this variable can be anywhere in your code.

The static variable (or field) in .net however does allow for a lot more protection. You can declare it private or protected to limit the code that can access or change it. This wil make debugging a lot easier becouse when an error occurs there are a lot less places in your code that can be responsible for it.

Comment: access modifiers aren't protection as much as guidelines